# Как скачать файл через ecxel PHP?

Tags: php, excel

Всем привет такая проблема, пытаюсь скачать файл через CURL запрос.
что делаю:

1. Делают запрос на url
2. Получаю ответ в виде
3. [image: Элемент списка]
4. делаю `file_put_contents('test.xlsx',$response)`

Файл он сохранил , но что внутри посмотрет не могу.
Кто может помочь с этим вопросом?

Если пытаюсь сохранить в xml вот файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код что пытаюсь сделать

```
$binaryData = curl_exec($curl);


$filePath = '/H643365903-LOOSE.xlsx';

$file = fopen($filePath, 'wb');


fwrite($file, $binaryData);


fclose($file);

echo 'Файл успешно создан: ' . $filePath;
```

Comment: В смысле — что внутри посмотреть не можете? Через Excel открывать пробовали?

Comment: Да, я хотел сохранить ответ с curl как excel , но при открытии пишет ошибку с данными